# How to fix TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, typeerror

I was trying a simple piece of code, get someone's name and age and let him/her know when they turn 21... not considering negatives and all that, just random.

I keep getting this `'int' object is not subscriptable` error.

```
name1 = raw_input("What's your name? ")
age1 = raw_input ("how old are you? ")
x = 0
int([x[age1]])
twentyone = 21 - x
print "Hi, " + name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + twentyone + " years."
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 4
      2 age1 = input ("how old are you? ")
      3 x = 0
----> 4 int([x[age1]])
      5 twentyone = 21 - x
      6 print "Hi, " + name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + twentyone + " years."

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Why does it say it is not subscriptable instead of saying it is not indexable?

Comment: @nog642 Because it doesn't include a `__getitem__()` method. The `x[n]` notation (indexing) is representative of mathematical subscripts. Hence *subscriptable*

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The problem is in the line,

```
int([x[age1]])
```

What you want is

```
x = int(age1)
```

You also need to convert the int to a string for the output...

```
print "Hi, " + name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + str(twentyone) + " years."
```

The complete script looks like,

```
name1 = raw_input("What's your name? ")
age1 = raw_input ("how old are you? ")
x = 0
x = int(age1)
twentyone = 21 - x
print "Hi, " + name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + str(twentyone) + " years."
```

Comment: The `x = 0` line is redundant.

Comment: Yes. This is python. We take pride in the fact that you don't have to declare variables!

Comment: Correct, the is line not needed. However, for clarity I modified only the parts containing errors.

Answer (score 118):

When you type `x = 0` that is creating a new `int` variable (name) and assigning a zero to it.

When you type `x[age1]` that is trying to access the `age1`'th entry, as if `x` were an array.

Comment: The only answer to actually explain what's going on, should be at the top.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation, this is a quality contribution

Answer (score 14):

'int' object is not subscriptable is TypeError in Python. To better understand how this error occurs, let us consider the following example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
print(list1[0][0])
```

If we run the code, you will receive the same TypeError in Python3.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here the index of the list is out of range. If the code was modified to:

```
print(list1[0])
```

The output will be 1(as indexing in Python Lists starts at zero), as now the index of the list is in range.

```
1
```

When the code(given alongside the question) is run, the TypeError occurs and it points to  line 4 of the code :

```
int([x[age1]])
```

The intention may have been to create a list of an integer number(although creating a list for a single number was not at all required). What was required was that to just assign the input(which in turn converted to integer) to a variable.

Hence, it's better to code this way:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
age = int(input('How old are you? '))
twenty_one = 21 - age
if(twenty_one < 0):
    print('Hi {0}, you are above 21 years' .format(name))
elif(twenty_one == 0):
    print('Hi {0}, you are 21 years old' .format(name))
else:
    print('Hi {0}, you will be 21 years in {1} year(s)' .format(name, twenty_one))
```

The output:

```
What's your name? Steve
How old are you? 21
Hi Steve, you are 21 years old
```

Answer (score 12):

When you write `x = 0`, `x` is an int...so you can't do `x[age1]` because `x` is `int`

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do here: `int([x[age1]])`?? It makes no sense.

You just have to cast the age input as an `int`:

```
name1 = raw_input("What's your name? ")
age1 = raw_input ("how old are you? ")
twentyone = 21 - int(age1)
print "Hi, %s you will be 21 in: %d years." % (name1, twentyone)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert age1 into int first, so it can do the minus. After that turn the result back to string for display:

```
name1 = raw_input("What's your name? ")
age1 = raw_input ("how old are you? ")
twentyone = str(21 - int(age1))
print "Hi, " + name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + twentyone + " years."
```

Answer (score 2):

```
name1 = input("What's your name? ")
age1 = int(input ("how old are you? "))
twentyone = str(21 - int(age1))

if age1<21:
    print ("Hi, " + name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + twentyone + " years.")

else:
    print("You are over the age of 21")
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot more simple just to do this;

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
age = int(input("How old are you? "))
print ("Hi,{0} you will be 21 in {1} years.".format(name, 21 - age))`
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, all these answers are correct, but here is a more modern way of doing this!

```
name1 : str = input("What's your name? ")
age1 : int = int(input ("how old are you? "))
twentyone : int = 21 - age1
print('Hi, {}, you will be 21 in: {} years'.format(name1, age1))
```

Answer (score 1):

x is already integer(x=0) and again you trying to make x again integer and also you gave indexing which is beyound the limit because x already has only one indexing (0) and you are trying to give indexing same as age so thats why you get this error. use this simple code

```
name1 = input("What's your name? ")
age1 = int(input ("how old are you?" ))
x=0
twentyone = str(21-age1)
print("Hi, " +name1+ " you will be 21 in: " + twentyone + " years.")
```