# Python - not subscriptable

Tags: python

I get error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
what should I do to fix it?

```
def permutation(k, s):
    r = s[:]
    for j in range(2, len(s)+1):
        r[j-1], r[k%j] = r[k%j], r[j-1]
        k = k/j+1
        return r
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.  The error seems to be in the code *calling* this function, so please show that code as well.  (The most probable cause is that you pass in an integer as `s`, but with the given information, this is only guessing.)

Comment: This is probably a formatting bug introduced when posting, but your "return r" is in an unusual place (inside the loop, I mean).

Comment: To fix it, don't subscript an int object. To get a better answer, tell us what your input is and what your expected output is.

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace the next time you need help, please?  Now we don't know where the error is exactly, but I think it is because you don't understand how `return` works: It returns to the calling place and goes on reading the source code after the function call...  So your function will return an integer only, but you probably think it returned a list and then you tried to get a specific item of the list, but of course this is not possible...  So: Save all `r`s in a list and return the list after the for loop. ;)

Comment: @Gandaro: Clearly the logic of this function is not sound.  However, r is originally a copy of s, and so returning r will return the list, not some integer.

Comment: @Darthfett Ah, you are right. But it can be of any subscriptable type, not only `list`. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/python-error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What line does this occur on? It seems likely that the line `r = s[:]` is the cause, and you would get that error if `s` wasn't a list or tuple.

You might want to look at [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably passing an 'int' object in as `s`, which the function clearly is treating as a list/tuple (or any other object that allows subscripting).  How are you using this function, and what is its purpose/intention?