# python - 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, arrays, knn

I am attempting a bit of knn classification. when i try to normalize the data in an array i keep getting the above error.

```
    norm_val = 100.00                                                              
    for i in range(0, len(ListData)):                                               
            ListData[i][0] = int(ListData[i][0]/max_val)
```

I'm getting the error on the last line which says, 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Thanks

Comment: This code is not enough to diagnose the problem. Most likely problem is that ListData is an integer and not an array or that ListData[i] is an integer and not an array.

Comment: Is your `ListData` a list of lists or just a simple list? If it is a simple list, `ListData[i][0]` is incorrect.

Comment: What does `ListData` look like?  Your code is assuming `ListData` contains sequences of integers, but your error message suggests it may contain just integers.

Comment: @Jules: It can't be an integer, or this code would fail on the line before when `len(ListData)` is called. So this code is perfectly enough to diagnose the problem. All the data is there.

Comment: 'ListData' contains values taken in from a text file that are ints and strings. i have the data being split every time a comma is come across. the data is just appended onto the end of the list then.

Comment: @Hiky: Could you post the contents of `ListData` in your question? Or at least part of it, enough to replicate the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/python-error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ListData` appears to be a list of integers (or at least a list that also contains integers).

Therefore, `ListData[i]` returns the `i`th integer of the list. And since there is no such thing as "the first element of an integer", so you get this error when trying to access `ListData[i][0]`.

Aside from that, if you're aiming to divide all items of a list by `max_val`, you can simply use a list comprehension:

```
ListData = [int(item/max_val) for item in ListData]
```

Comment: You could write `int(item/max_val)` as `item // max_val`

Comment: @Daenyth: It's not quite the same: `2//3.0` returns `0.0`, so if max_val is a float, you'd get a list of floats, not of ints.

Answer (score 2):

`ListData` contains not only lists but also other objects which are not lists.

The following works:

```
ListData = [ [99, "Some thing"],
             [88, "Some other thing"] ]
```

The following does not:

```
ListData = [ 99,
             88 ]
```

It is not really clear what you want to do.