# what does 'int' object is not subscriptable mean?

Tags: python, python-3.3

After some research I still do not know what

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

means, all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: Do you want to solve this error? Or just want to understand what does it mean? If you want the first one, please paste your code and full trackback. If you want the second one, then **duplicate of:** [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/python-error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable) and [In Python, what does it mean if an object is subscriptable or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not).

Answer (score 8):

It means you can't do `i[1]` if `i` is an integer.

Comment: so that means that I have to change this then name:score[0]

Comment: I guess. What are you trying to do? Maybe more context would help.