# How to fix "int object is not subscriptable" in Python in the following code?

Tags: python

Each word needs to be on a different line in a given statement and am not able to print the last word.

```
# [ ] Print each word in the quote on a new line  
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
start = 0
space_index = quote.find(" ")
while space_index != -1:
    print(quote[start:space_index])
    start = space_index+1
    space_index = quote.find(" ",start)
    if space_index == -1:
        print(space_index[start:])
```

```
Expected output:
they
stumble
who
run
fast
```

I am not able to print the last word: "fast"

Comment: The error: `print(space_index[start:])`. Sure you know that `space_index` is a number.

Comment: You people are so quick. I just found it myself, yet within minutes I received four answers.

Comment: `print(*quote.split(), sep='\n')` does this for you, unless you are trying to make your own version for practice.

Comment: @Coder_G - That would suggest you didn't research your own issue much before posting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does 'int' object is not subscriptable mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647685/what-does-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-mean)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `print(quote[start:])`.  And there are *much* simpler ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last code as below. Most probably it is a typo error.

```
if space_index == -1: 
    print(space_index[start:])
```

to:

```
if space_index == -1: 
    print(quote[start:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is space_index is an int and you intended to do  `print(quote[start:])` instead.

Alternatively, you might like to do the following

```
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
quote = quote.split()
for i in quote:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`space_index` is an integer so you cannot do:

```
print(space_index[start:])
```

This is because for the same reason you cannot do, for example, `2[3:]`.

You need to use:

```
print(quote[start:])
```

---

A better approach for this problem is just:

```
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
print(*quote.split(), sep='\n')
```

which prints:

```
they
stumble
who
run
fast
```