# Python issue with TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, charts

So I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" the code I'm using is below:

```
 def make_chart(size, items):
    keys = list(items.keys())
    chart = list()
    row = []
    for r in range(len(keys)):
        for i in range(size):
            row.append({"w":0, "v":0, "keys":[]})
        chart.append(row)
    return chart

def fill_chart(size, items, chart):
    keys = list(items.keys())
    vals = []
    wts = []
    for v in range(len(chart)):
        for y in range(len(chart[v])):
            vals.append(items[keys[v]]['w'])
            wts.append(items[keys[v]]['v'])
    w, h = size +1, len(vals)
    table = [[ 0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
    for index in range(len(vals)):
        for weight in range(w):
            if wts[index] > weight:
                table[index][weight] = table[index -1][weight]
                continue
            prior_values = table[index - 1][weight]
            new_option_best = vals[index] + table[index - 1][weight - wts]
            table[index][weight] = max(prior_values, new_option_best)
    solution_arr = []
    for x in table:
        for y in x:
            solution_arr.append(y)
    return max([x for y in table for x in y])

def main():
    iphone = {"w": 1, "v": 3000}
    guitar = {"w": 1, "v": 2000}
    tablet = {"w": 2, "v": 3000}
    dog = {"w":1, "v": 4000}
    items = {"iphone":iphone, "guitar":guitar, "tablet":tablet, "dog":dog}

    chart = make_chart(4, items)
    chart = fill_chart(4, items, chart)

    for i in range(len(items.keys())):
        print("---{0}".format(list(items.keys()))[i])
        for j in range(len(chart[i])):
            print(chart[i][j])
    print(len(chart))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the error is occuring at "for j in range(len(chart[i])):"
all I'm trying to do is print the chart. I've looked through the other answers to this error but nothing seems to fulfill what is happening in this code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: It looks like `chart` is a number. Debug to find out why.

Comment: Your code requires that fill_chart returns 2-demension array, but it returns an integer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your fill_chart function returns integer, not list.