# Can you see what's wrong here : Python For Loop will not run, 'Int not subscriptable'

Tags: python

Relatively new to Python, so apologies if this is a silly question. I'm replicating a piece of code which shows the difference in computation speeds between vectorised and non-vectorised calculations in Numpy Python. As far as I can tell, I have perfectly replicated the code where it says 'int is not subscriptable' . As far as I can tell all variables have been clearly defined ( i.e. a and b have defined values, and c is set to 0 which i in range is iterating over

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.random.randint(1000000)
b = np.random.randint(1000000)

# Vectorised

tic = time.time()

# c is computed as multiplying 2 x 1 dimensional Matrices
c = np.dot(a,b)
toc = time.time()

print(c)

# We multiply by 1000 so that we can see the time elapsed for the 
# calculation in ms
print("Vectorised version:" + str(1000*(toc-tic)) + "ms")

# Non - Vectorised (iterating over a for loop)

c = 0
tic = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    c += a[i]*b[i] <--- Error tracks to here
toc = time.time()

print(c)
print("For loop:" + str(1000*(toc-tic)) + "ms")
```

Any help is welcome, I have tried searching a few thread including this one : [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

But after driving myself mad for 30 minutes I thought I would finally ask my first question!

Comment: a and b are integers and not lists.

Comment: You assign an `np.random.randint` to `a` and `b`. `a[i]` and `b[i]` make no sense. What do you want to do inside the loop?

Comment: As stated, `a` and `b` returned are do not contain multiple values, they contain a random integer between 0 and 1000000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to input the `size` argument to `np.random.randint(1000000)`, so it returned an integer instead of an array. Try this:

```
a = np.random.randint(1000000, size=42)
b = np.random.randint(1000000, size=42)
```

See 
[the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).

Comment: Thanks ! I can see I put in np.random.randint which should be np.random.rand

Comment: @MichaelMuttiah The problem is not that you call the wrong method but that you call a method wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

as in the comments, a and b are integers, not arrays, so need to change a and b to arrays for the code to work, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.random.randint(10, size=1000000)
b = np.random.randint(10, size=1000000)

# Vectorised

tic = time.time()

# c is computed as multiplying 2 x 1 dimensional Matrices
c = np.dot(a,b)
toc = time.time()

print(c)

# We multiply by 1000 so that we can see the time elapsed for the 
# calculation in ms
print("Vectorised version:" + str(1000*(toc-tic)) + "ms")

# Non - Vectorised (iterating over a for loop)

c = 0
tic = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    c += a[i]*b[i]
toc = time.time()

print(c)
print("For loop:" + str(1000*(toc-tic)) + "ms")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters mentioned you were specifying the range of the random integers not the amount of random integers that you requested.

You can also use np.rand.rand which expects the dimensions of the returned np.array and not the range parameters. That of course will give you a floating point vector performance gain and not integer performace gain which may have been what you were looking for.

For future reference you can check the type and size of variables in python:

```
a = np.random.randint(1000000)
b = np.random.randint(1000000)
print ("a type : ", type(a))
print ("b type : ", type(b))
print ("a size : ", a.size)
print ("b size : ", b.size)
```

Results in:

```
a type :  <class 'int'>
b type :  <class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crud.py", line 9, in <module>
    print ("a size : ", a.size)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Now we see that a and b are integers rather than arrays, and we get an unsurprising error when we try to determine their size.

Changing the definition of a and b to include the size parameter gives us numpy arrays as expected and then the rest of the code works too.

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=1000000)
b = np.random.randint(10, size=1000000)
print ("a type : ", type(a))
print ("b type : ", type(b))
print ("a size : ", a.size)
print ("b size : ", b.size)
```

Which results in (including the timing output):

```
a type :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
b type :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
a size :  1000000
b size :  1000000
20252846
Vectorised version:1.0726451873779297ms
20252846
For loop:264.2645835876465ms
```