# Why does converting an integer to a string, slicing it, and then converting it back to an integer give me this TypeError?

Tags: python, algorithm, compiler-errors, runtime-error

So I'm trying to solve a challenge [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/utopian-tree/problem), and I have a basic algorithm written to solve this problem.  One of the functions of this algorithm is that it will convert the input of the function, n, to a string, slice every character but the first, and convert it back to an integer using this: `o = int(str(n[:1]))`.  When I do this however, it gives me this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.  I have found another case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable), but it does not seem to solve my problem.  What does this error mean and how can I rid my code of it?

Full function:

```
def utopianTree(n):
    o = int(str(n[:1]))
    n = int(str(n[1:]))

    for i in range(1, n):
        if n == 0:
            o += 1
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            o *= 2
        elif i % 2 != 0:
            o += 1
        i += 1
    return o
```

Comment: Isn't `n` an integer? If so, Python is right, you _can't_ use the subscript operator on `n`. Maybe you meant to convert `n` to a string first?

Comment: `n` is a integer, you can't slice integers because they are not sequences.

Comment: Your English says "convert, slice, convert", but your code says "slice, convert, convert".

Comment: you meant `int(str(n)[:1])`?

Comment: Why are you doing string manipulation at all?
Other than reading the input, the problem deals entirely with integers.

Comment: @Prune because I am setting the value of o to be the first digit of the *n* digit integer that is the input, and converting it to a string, slicing it, and converting to an int seems to be the most obvious and therefore most pythonic way of doing so.

Comment: *What* 3-digit integer?  The problem specification has an integer on each line of the input.

Comment: @Prune I shouldn't have said 3 digits, the input could be anywhere from 1 to 10 digits, but the input for the function that the site gives is 3 digits.

Comment: @Jodast: No, it doesn't give ten digits.  "The first line contains an integer, , the number of test cases.  Subsequent lines each contain an integer, denoting the number of cycles for that test case.  1 <= t <=10; 0 <= n <= 60"

Comment: @Prune okay then, I guess I was just reading it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the `[:1]` slice to `n`, which is an integer. You can't slice integers, because they are not sequences.

Your title states you want convert to a string, then slice, then convert back to an integer, but you are not actually doing that. Put the slice operation on the `str()` outcome instead:

```
o = int(str(n)[:1])
n = int(str(n)[1:])
```

The first number assigned to `o` is the highest digit, so you could just repeatedly divide by 10 until the number is smaller than 10:

```
o = n
while o > 10:
    o //= 10
```

or you could take the log10 of the value so you know by how many powers of 10 to shift the value; you can get the remaining digits of `n` by using the same magnitude value:

```
import math

magnitude = int(math.log10(n))
o = n // (10 ** magnitude)
n -= o * (10 ** magnitude)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> n = 4213
>>> magnitude = int(math.log10(n))
>>> o = n // (10 ** magnitude)
>>> n -= o * (10 ** magnitude)
>>> o, n
(4, 213)
```

Take into account that any zeros in the value are not going to be preserved; `1024` becomes `1` and `24`, with the fact that there was a zero between these two pairs is lost. That applies to both the int-string-slice-int and the arithmetic approach. Only keeping `n` as a series of string digits would keep that information.

Comment: Grammar nazi ;-) +1

Comment: Oh, I see.  It seems I just got them out of order,  Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianDean: sorry, I obsessively edit and expand my answers for a while, so that clashed.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as just changing it to `o = int(str(n)[:1])`

Hope this helps!