# 'int' object is not subscriptable // python matrix issue

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to code below instructions and I get the "'int' object is not subscriptable" in line 3. Would you please help me see what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Instructions:
Given 2 arrays of ints, a and b, return True if they have the same first element or they have the same last element. Both arrays will be length 1 or more.
i.e:common_end([1, 2, 3], [7, 3]) → True

Code:

```
def common_end(a, b):
    if len(a)>=1 and len(b)>=1:
        if (a[0][0]==b[1][0] or a[0][len(a)-1]== b[0][len(b)-1]):----> Error Line
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: How are you invoking your function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are double indexing your arrays (i.e. `a[0][0]`) - this will only work for multidimensional arrays.

To get the first element of an array you can do: `a[0]`

To get the last element of an array you can do: `a[-1]`

Therefore you can rewrite line 3 as follows:

```
if (a[0]==b[0] or a[-1]==b[-1]):
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I confused myself with a multidimensional array. The solution totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a flat list as if it were two-dimensional. `a[0][0]` is going to find an int at `a[0]` and crash when you try to access its 'first element' by doing `a[0][0]`.

You should use a nested loop instead where you compare the lists' numbers.

Comment: Thanks WorkShoft!. I'll have the nested loop in mind for the next challenge. Regards!