# I am trying to the save the result of the clustering I did and is showing this error message 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class UserCluster(object):
    def load_data(self):
        print('loading data')
        user_ids = list(Rating.user_id)
        content_ids = list(Rating.isbn)
        num_users = len(user_ids)
        user_rating = dok_matrix((num_users, len(content_ids)), dtype=np.float32)

        print('data loaded')

        return user_ids, user_ratings
    def calculate(self, k =23):
        print("Training K-means clustering")
        user_ids, user_ratings = self.load_data()

        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k)
        clusters = kmeans.fit(user_ratings)
        #plot(user_ratings.todense(), kmeans, k)

        self.save_clusters(clusters, user_ids)

        return clusters
    def save_clusters(self, clusters, user_ids):
        print("Saving clusters")
        #Cluster.objects.all().delete()
        for i, cluster_label in enumerate(clusters.labels_):
            Cluster(cluster_id=cluster_label, user_id=user_ids[i]['user_id']).save()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("Calculating user clusters...")
```

I tried running the code above. The clustering was successful, but trying to save it is the issue as it is showing this:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is here:

```
for i, cluster_label in enumerate(clusters.labels_):
            Cluster(cluster_id=cluster_label, user_id=user_ids[i]['user_id']).save()
```

Specifically the `user_id=user_ids[i]['user_id']` part.

This question has an answer that goes over the basics of this type error fairly well:
[Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python)