# Getting Type error : 'int' object is not subscriptable in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm programming a 2 set of 4 digits number that check that if it any digit that is the same like
the program will random 4 digits number such as 3415 and user have to guess that number by input 4 digits number such as 5213 so if there're 3 that matches but in a different position that will print ◘ or 'white' and 1 that matches and have the same position that will print • or 'black'.

So I'm getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. (line 48)

```
import random

#---------------------- RANDOM INT ------------------------------#

number="%04d" % random.randint(0,9999)
#print(number)
b = str(number)
numlist=[]

for digit in b:
    numlist.append (int(digit))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#

#----------------------- INPUT --------------------------------------#

enter = int(input('Enter 4 digits number : '))
c = str(enter)
enlist=[]

for digit in c:
    enlist.append (int(digit))

#enlist = int(enlist)
print(enlist)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#--------------------- DEFINING -------------------------------------#

black=0
white=0
false=0

i = range(0,3)
j = range(0,3)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------#

print(numlist)

#i = int(i)
#j = int(j)

for numlist in range(0,4):
    for enlist in range(0,4):
        if i==j:
            if enlist[i]==numlist[j]:  #THIS LINE
                black =+ 1
            else:
                false =+ 1
        else:
            if enlist[i]==numlist[j]:
                white =+1
            else:
                false =+ 1

print(black*"•" , white*"◘")
```

Comment: Try `i[enlist]==j[numlist]`

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use numlist and enlist as iterable they become converted to ints in range(0,4), Hence you get the error.
Instead try this:

```
for i in range(len(enlist)):
 for j in range(len(numlist)):
    if i==j:
        if enlist[i]==numlist[j]:  #THIS LINE
            black =+ 1
        '''
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loops, you overwrite enlist & numlist with integers, and you trying to access it as a list, change the variable names in the for loop.

Use a single for loop

```
for i in range(len(enlist)):
    if(enlist[i] == numlist[i]:
        # your code
```