# multiplication returning error (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm quite new in python. could anyone help to solve this error?

```
def distance_constraint(coords):
    cos = 0.099567846
    sin = 0.995030775
    outer = 2

    t = (coords[outer, 1] * cos) - (coords[outer, 0] * sin)
    return t

print(distance_constraint(5))
```

Comment: This is due to this expression `coords[outer, 1]`. What did you expect to get here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python)

Comment: In order to o solve this, we must know what behavior you actually expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed `5` as `coords`, but `5[outer,1]` makes no sense.  An integer can't be subscripted with `[]`.

The value of `coords` is likely supposed to be a `numpy.array` of at least three coordinate pairs:

```
import numpy as np

def distance_constraint(coords):
    cos = 0.099567846
    sin = 0.995030775
    outer = 2

    t = (coords[outer, 1] * cos) - (coords[outer, 0] * sin)
    return t

coords = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print(distance_constraint(coords))  # outer,0 and outer,1 would refer to [5,6]
```

Output:

```
-4.3777467990000005
```