# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable,python

Tags: python

Below is My code.

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")
new_two_digit_number = int(two_digit_number)
print(new_two_digit_number[0] + new_two_digit_number[1])"""
```

if i type 27 on two_digit_number code, i'd like to print "9" for answer.
But showed up TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I already know the right code, but dont' understand why showed up above error..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python)

Answer (score 0):

> [Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python)

`new_two_digit_number` is an `int`. Not a `string`. If you want to access the individual numbers, you need to cast to a `str`, then add them together as `int`s:

```py
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")
new_two_digit_number = int(two_digit_number)
new_two_digit_number = str(two_digit_number)
print(int(new_two_digit_number[0]) + int(new_two_digit_number[1]))
```

---

Or you can use a list comprehension to do it all in one line:

```
def add_digits(num: str) -> int:
    """Converts a string (input), to an integer sum of all the numbers in the string"""
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(int(num)))
```